# Javascript closures returns NaN?

Tags: javascript

Trying to follow example in "Javascript: The Good Parts", creating a closure to be achieve hiding.  In the case a simple "account" object which has a balance that can't be changed directly:

```
    <head>
<script>
    var myapp = {};
    var account = function() {
        var value = 0;
        return {
            "account_name": "",
            deposit: function (amount) {
                value = this.value + amount;
            },
            withdrawal: function (amount) {
                value = this.value - amount;
            },
            balance: function( ) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }();
    myapp.account = account;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    myapp.account.account_name = "Fred";
    myapp.account.deposit(100);
    myapp.account.withdrawal(25);

    document.writeln("<p>Account name = " + myapp.account.account_name + "</p>");

    document.writeln("<p>Balance = " + myapp.account.balance( ) + "</p>");


</script>
</body>
```

which yields the following:

> Account name = Fred
>
> Balance = NaN

Wny NaN?

Comment: BTW, it's usual to write immediately invoked function expressions (IIFEs) with surrounding brackets like `var f = (function(){...}())` so it's easier to see that they are an IIFE rather than a plain function expression before you get to the end of the block and see `...}()`. I thought Crockford wrote them this way too.

Comment: Actually not, at least in the section on Crockford section closures I was referring to.  But probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you never set `this.value`. Basically, this can be fixed to just reference the closure'd variable `value`:

```
var myapp = {};
var account = function() {
    var value = 0;
    return {
        "account_name": "",
        deposit: function (amount) {
            value = value + amount;
        },
        withdrawal: function (amount) {
            value = value - amount;
        },
        balance: function( ) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}();
myapp.account = account;
myapp.account.account_name = "Fred";
myapp.account.deposit(100);
myapp.account.withdrawal(25);

$('p:nth-child(1)').text('Account name = ' + myapp.account.account_name);
$('p:nth-child(2)').text('Balance = ' + myapp.account.balance());
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pjb9kga/)

Comment: Aha. Thanks.  So what does 'this' refer to?  Not the function, but the object returned by the function?

Comment: yes, that's the case. Basically, even if `this` referred to function, it would still be undefined, because `var value =` is not the same as `this.value =`

Comment: @user1023110: `this` never refers to the function unless explicitly set so. Learn more about `this` from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this or https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md

Comment: @user1023110— *this* doesn't refer to the object returned by the function either. It's set by how the function is called (or use of *bind*).

Answer (score 0):

Try it: i'm changed little bit your code.... this.value change into only value..

```
<head>
<script>
    var myapp = {};
    var account = function() {
        var value = 0;
        return {
            "account_name": "",
            deposit: function (amount) {
                value = value + amount;
            },
            withdrawal: function (amount) {
                value = value - amount;
            },
            balance: function( ) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }();
    myapp.account = account;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    myapp.account.account_name = "Fred";
    myapp.account.deposit(100);
    myapp.account.withdrawal(25);

    document.writeln("<p>Account name = " + myapp.account.account_name + "</p>");

    document.writeln("<p>Balance = " + myapp.account.balance( ) + "</p>");


</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you assign `account` to `myapp`, the `scope` is missing, put `var value` outside the function

```
var myapp = {};
var value = 0;
var account = (function(val){
        return{
            value: val,
            "account_name": "",
            deposit: function (amount) {
                value = this.value + amount;
            },
            withdrawal: function (amount) {
                value = this.value - amount;
            },
            balance: function( ) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    })(value);
console.log(account);
myapp.account = account;


myapp.account.account_name = "Fred";
myapp.account.deposit(100);
myapp.account.withdrawal(25);

console.log("<p>Account name = " + myapp.account.account_name + "</p>");

console.log("<p>Balance = " + myapp.account.balance( ) + "</p>");
```